# How do I clear the screen without deleting channel history?

Tags: slack

Channel history is useful, but despite slack's new message notification system, I find myself unnecessarily scanning old parts of a conversation frequently, and would like to hide it from the screen.

Is there a slack command or technique to hide on-screen messages, or to push them above the fold, once I am finished reading messages in a channel?

Shell Terminal applications and IRC clients implement this functionality, and it's very useful to suppress distractions.

Comment: One technique is to use a channel - have that message in a channel, you can close the channel afterward. (this does, of course, require that you know you are going to want to hide the messages before the conversation begins.)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of feature is not supported by Slack.

I got in touch with them, and this is the official response:

> Unfortunately, the option to hide on screen messages is not something
>   we currently offer with Slack, although I see how useful this feature
>   could be. I'm happy to pass this along as a suggestion to the team for
>   future consideration! My apologies we don't currently offer this
>   feature or something similar. (Amie, Slack Support)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this too, to begin to look for messages from the clear point (like we do in terminal with CMD-K).

My solution to this is very specific to my case (waiting for a Slackbot to respoind to some action I've taken elsewhere). I add a new message at the clear point in the public channel, something like `---- MERGED PR INTO K8 DEPLOY ----` which could just be a horizontal line or a Slackmoji, too.

Comment: That is a nice approach. Did you find a way to do this so that only you see the message, or do other members of the channel see it too?

Comment: Unfortunately others must see it. On the other hand, you could thumbs-up a post or something more discreet if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

While what you are asking is exactly not possible, until Slack makes a feature around this. Until then though, you could possibly make use of [Channel Tools](https://slack.com/apps/A018HK8FDB5-channel-tools).

It comes with a `/clear` command. When executed, it pushes all the existing messages one full screen up. Thereby, creating some breathing space and clearing screen in the API's limitations.

**Before**:

[image: Before /clear command for clearing screen on Slack]

**After**:

[image: After /clear command for clearing screen on Slack]

Because it creates an ephemeral message, all the changes are only visible to the user executing the command.